# Neo4j- Avoid multiple relationships getting created between the same nodes in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to restrict the relationships getting created , if already created between the existing nodes. Right now its getting created multiple times? Is there any command similar to 'merge' for restricting duplicate relationships?Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User MERGE instead of CREATE while creating relationships.

```
MERGE (Product)-[:listed_under_category]->(level3)
MERGE (level3)-[:child_of]->(level2)
```

Answer (score 1):

hey i think the mix up but i need more information. Is that merge, merges the the whole statement. so if he does not find a "match" for the whole statement the database "creates" the whole statement.

So when you type something like merge (a)-[]->(b)-[]->(q)
if you already have (a)-[]->(b)

he will recreate (a)-[]->(b)-[]->(q) and  you have in the db  (a)-[]->(b)-[]->(q) , (a)-[]->(b)

but if you type merge (a)-[]->(b) merge(b)-[]->(q)

and you know that you have the nodes. Neo4j merge will create the relations if there are no relations. and match if there are relations

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, CREATE UNIQUE may be the solution you are looking for.  For example:

```
create (a:Ex {name: 'A'})-[r:inside]->(b:Ex {name: 'B'}) return a, b, r
```

sets up your original     (a)-[]->(b) relationship.  Then to extend the relationship in the manner you proposed ....

```
match (a)-[:inside]->(b) where a.name = 'A' and b.name = 'B'
create unique (a)-[:inside]->(b)-[:inside]->(q:Ex {name: 'Q'})
return a, b, q
```

CREATE UNIQUE also works if the relationships are different:

```
match (a)-[:inside]->(b) where a.name = 'A' and b.name = 'B'
create unique (a)-[:inside]->(b)-[:under]->(q:Ex {name: 'Q'})
return a, b, q
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MERGE` clause also avoids duplicating relationships.